# Why I can't just use class from Pod of CocoaPods

Tags: ios, swift, charts, frameworks

I have installed Pod to use iOS Charts but stuck at the first line of code!
[image]

tried build and clean project - nothing
Tried to link binary with libraries with Charts-framework and then import Charts but there is warning that my project is inside of Charts module so import is ignored.

Can't understand why this class (or other classes from this pod) is not visible for main project?

Comment: are you using the xcode project file or xcode workspace?

Comment: workspace, did't say that

Comment: can you link to the library ? i mean its github link

Comment: @Shubhank here is cocoaPods link https://cocoapods.org/pods/Charts

Comment: you need to import the Charts module according to the instructions. try adding `@import Charts` to your class

Comment: @Shubhank I wrote about import in my question. It is ignored because project within Charts module.

Comment: can you drop by to the chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26424/iosandroidchaosoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the lib, the pod has been written in swift so make sure your pod file has `use_frameworks!` command in it.

Also currently the project name and the pod name are same that is **Charts**.
This can lead to path issues. please solve that by changing name of the project.
It will work

Comment: Was exactly the same name and that was my mistake! Thank you!